# Azure Site-to-Site VPN and Fortigate IPSec Phase 2 error on SA re-establishment - "peer SA proposal not match local policy"

Tags: azure, fortigate, azure-vpn

I am documenting this for posterity. After a period of IPSEC tunnel being succesfully up and working beteen Azure VPN Gateway and Fortigate 200 E firewall running FortiOS v6.4.4 build1803 (GA), the tunnel drops and does not re-establish itself for a while (in my case about an hour) and then resume again as if nothing happened.

[image]
Fortigate log file contains the following useful entries of which the error "peer SA proposal not match local policy" is indicative:

```
date=2021-01-03 time=04:22:03 eventtime=1609618924346452242 tz="+0800" logid="0101037129" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="notice" vd="root" logdesc="Progress IPsec phase 2" msg="progress IPsec phase 2" action="negotiate" remip=1.2.3.4 locip=5.6.7.8 remport=500 locport=500 outintf="wan1" cookies="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" user="N/A" group="N/A" useralt="N/A" xauthuser="N/A" xauthgroup="N/A" assignip=N/A vpntunnel="AZURE-XYZ" status="success" init="remote" exch="CREATE_CHILD" dir="outbound" role="responder" result="DONE" version="IKEv2"
date=2021-01-03 time=04:22:03 eventtime=1609618924346420462 tz="+0800" logid="0101037125" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="error" vd="root" logdesc="IPsec phase 2 error" msg="IPsec phase 2 error" action="negotiate" remip=1.2.3.4 locip=5.6.7.8 remport=500 locport=500 outintf="wan1" cookies="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" user="N/A" group="N/A" useralt="N/A" xauthuser="N/A" xauthgroup="N/A" assignip=N/A vpntunnel="AZURE-XYZ" status="negotiate_error" reason="peer SA proposal not match local policy"
date=2021-01-03 time=04:22:03 eventtime=1609618924346376500 tz="+0800" logid="0101037120" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="notice" vd="root" logdesc="Negotiate IPsec phase 1" msg="negotiate IPsec phase 1" action="negotiate" remip=1.2.3.4 locip=5.6.7.8 remport=500 locport=500 outintf="wan1" cookies="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" user="N/A" group="N/A" useralt="N/A" xauthuser="N/A" xauthgroup="N/A" assignip=N/A vpntunnel="AZURE-XYZ" status="success" result="N/A" peer_notif="N/A"
```

Azure VPN gateway contains no useful diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to install a custom IPSec policy with Azure VPN Gateway as described in this [Azure troubleshooting document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-disconnected-intermittently?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support). Make sure you pick compatible policy options (I chose AES256/SHA256 everywhere) and disable PFS. THe [how-to is described here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-ipsecikepolicy-rm-powershell#managepolicy). When you follow the guide you will by default have no IPSec Policy installed - this is counter-intuitive as the gateway of course has a policy, but it is the default one and thus hidden. Just follow the guide.

Upvote or comment if you feel this has saved you some head banging.